# Angular 2 import statement wildcard syntax

Tags: typescript, angular

I defined several classes in one file like this

my.classes.ts

```
export class Class1 {....}
export class Class2 {....}
export class Class3 {....}
```

Now I want to import them all using wildcard like this

```
import {*} from './my.classes';
```

It showed syntax error.

What is the correct syntax to import * from a module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go,

```
 import * as MyClasses from './my.classes';
 
 MyClasses.Class1 ....
```

Comment: Excellent. Very much appreciated.