# Typescript wildcard import all module names into current namespace?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I want to have the ability to not have to type a module name (even an alias for a module) in front of all the places I am using a value from that module. (I'd rather not have to e.g. resort to running the C pre processor so I can do #include type stuff.)

(Close but no cigar: [Angular 2 import statement wildcard syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287913/angular-2-import-statement-wildcard-syntax))

I want

```
import * from "./MyModule";
console.log( foobar );
```

instead of annoying stuff like:

```
console.log( MyModule.foobar )
```

or:

```
import * as M from "./MyModule";
console.log( M.foobar );
```

Comment: Why you do not want to import your module to a specific variables? Like so
`import {yourVariable} from "./myModule";`

Comment: What you want is a global `with` equivalent, considered to be a bad practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import * from "./MyModule";
```

is not part of the ES Module specification. You cannot simply inject members into the scope without naming them. Identifier conflicts could arise whenever a module changed.

As @haim770 points out in his comment, this would be very much like the much maligned (and very rightly so) `with` statement.

It is simply not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

**Typescript wildcard import all module names into current namespace?**

It is bad practice **why?**

Say you have couple hundreds modules in you MyModule and you want to import all think of how many unnecessary modules are going to import which you may will not use and that will take memory and make your app slow, You should import import the only module you want to work with.

e.g

```
import {A, D} from './MyModules';
```

If you still want to use wild card which will import all your modules

e.g

```
import * as http from "http"
```

then you should also use tree shaking so when deploying your app you can get rid off all other unnecessary modules.

Hope this helps

Comment: Appreciated! I personally completely disagree with the rationale, at least for programs-in-the-small. (The fact that it goes against some standard that Typescript maybe tries to be following is more of an argument from authority that I can unhappily accept even if I also don't like that one ethically either.)

Comment: Right it's not about performance, it's just explicit dependency declaration and scoping. In other languages we are often used to merge-importing entire namespaces, but ECMAScript does not permit this. Part of this has to do with the way the language is designed where the global object namspace object in a browser is actually the window and it has a ton of members. I think that for _truly_ small programs it is somewhat of an annoyance, like a syntactic tax, but it's a tax worth paying. Of course you can create a prelude module that attaches globals

Comment: But what will happened when you will bundle your files to on file? It will also bundle all unnecessary modules which you are not using. By performance i mean it will be heavy to load unused code in browser.

Comment: @MrJSingh In theory it would still be possible to tree shake imports if they were injected into the surrounding scope. I just think performance is not the primary reason, I would say it has to do with maintainability.